# How can I access my User custom properties defined in my AWS Cognito User Pools?

Tags: objective-c, attributes, amazon-cognito

I added a few custom properties in the User configuration off my AWS Cognito User Pool. I have my app in objective-c similar to the sample project CognitoYourUserPoolsSample. Everything works fine and I can sign-in/sign-up without any problem.

Though, I don't know how to access and set all the User custom attributes that I added in the User Pool config. I can access the default attributes values from the response object AWSCognitoIdentityProviderGetUserResponse for example. They are stored in the _userAttributes property (e.g. phone, email, etc.).

**My questions are:**

- Where are the custom attributes stored?
- What is the proper way to set them during sign-up?

I get the following error when I try to sign-up with custom attributes using the same approach as the default attributes:

```
// add custom attributes
AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType * subscriptionType = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType new];
subscriptionType.name = @"subscriptionType";
subscriptionType.value = @"Premium";
[attributes addObject:subscriptionType];
```

[Here is the error I get.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kl0KO.png)

```
responseObjectForResponse:originalRequest:currentRequest:data:error:] | Response body:
{"__type":"NotAuthorizedException","message":"A client attempted to write unauthorized attribute"}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Answering my own question with a temporary solution while waiting for some info. Instead of adding a bunch of custom attributes I simply decided to use the 'profile' default attribute. I store a bunch of user related profile data as a JSON String. Makes sense right? (e.g. isSubscribed, subscriptionType, credit, etc.). I can also visualize the values on the Cognito User Pools admin console which you can't do with custom attributes.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your questions:

1. Custom attributes are stored internally by Cognito, custom attributes can be seen from the response of a DescribeUserPool call.
2. They should be set on pool creation from the Cognito console. They are not allowed to be set from a client, which is why you saw issues.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When you say "should be set" you mean created? I created them from the Cognito console but I would need to populate them from my app. Is this doable?

Comment: Yes, it can be done through AdminUpdateUserAttributes or UpdateUserAttributes.

Comment: @Yisha i have user specific data in my custom attribute, that i need to set/get when user is authenticated, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

As I found in the issue: 
[Signup with custom attributes in Cognito user pools](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js/issues/1084)
to set the value for custom attribute you must set a write permissions for it.
Open Amazon Cognito Console -> YourPool -> General Settings -> App Clients -> Show Details -> Set attribute read and write permissions and activate checkboxes for your custom attributes.

Also in code attribute name should contain a prefix 'custom:' 
i.e. subscriptionType.name = @"custom:subscriptionType"; and those values are shown in AWS console.